# Delete closing values

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe (see Figure) with float values (latitude/longitude) and I want to delete closest values with accuracy 0.02. For example:

```
[0.03, 0.05, 0.04, 0.06] -> [0.04]
```

How can I do it with pandas methods?

[image]

Comment: Hi nikita, welcome to SO. Please provide an example dataset with expected output and show what you have tried allready.

Comment: Please refrain from using links to external sites as it makes it harder to reproduce the problem. Also provide sample inputs and expected outputs - you can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the example you have provided ? You say you want to delete the closest values with accuracy 0.02, why is 0.04 the only one remaining in the end ? Why have 0.03, 0.05, 0.06 been removed ? Is there some value you need to check against ?

Comment: How do you define the closeness of latitude/longitude coordinates - as great-circle distance, or as spherical taxicab distance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the querist doesn't care to provide more details, the problem is interesting. I take that the given coordinate points are to be consolidated into groups where the latitude and longitude values are not more than two times the *accuracy* apart, respectively, i. e. within a square-like cluster, and that each cluster is to be concentrated to one point near the center. This problem can be approached by ordering the points (e. g. with the aid of the [scikit-learn OPTICS](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#optics) implementation), splitting them into groups meeting the clustering condition and applying the selection of a near-central point.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'lon': (20.489192, 20.47559,  20.481381, 20.4422,   20.474462),
                   'lat': (54.719898, 54.720311, 54.731917, 54.710419, 54.72706 )},
                  index=[3, 4, 20, 21, 24])

def group(x, minmax_group): # this function clusters points within +/- 0.02
    if not hasattr(x, "__len__"): x = (x, ) # if it has to work for the one-dimensional case
    # in two-dimensional case, x is coordinate pair (longitude, latitude)
    # minmax_group[0][min] is the minimum coordinate pair (lower left) of a cluster
    # minmax_group[0][max] is the maximum coordinate pair (upper right) of a cluster
    # minmax_group[1] is the sequential index of the cluster
    if minmax_group[0] is None: minmax_group[:] = {min:x, max:x}, 0 # first cluster
    # check if longitude or latitude outside of current cluster
    elif any(x[l] < minmax_group[0][max][l]-.04
                 or minmax_group[0][min][l]+.04 < x[l] for l in range(len(x))):
        minmax_group[0] = {min:x, max:x}
        minmax_group[1] += 1                # new cluster
    else:
        for m in minmax_group[0]:           # store current minimum/maximum coordinates
            minmax_group[0][m] = tuple(m(minmax_group[0][m][l], x[l]) for l in range(len(x)))
    return minmax_group[1]

from sklearn.cluster import OPTICS
opt = OPTICS().fit(df)  # order the points
# group the points; set index because only index is passed to groupby function
dt = df.reset_index().set_index(['lon', 'lat']).iloc[opt.ordering_].groupby(
    lambda x, minmax_group=[None]: group(x, minmax_group)).apply(
    # choose point at the center of the group; set index back to original
    lambda g: g.reset_index().iloc[[(len(g)-1)//2]]).set_index('index').rename_axis(None)
print(dt)
```

Output of this example:

```
         lon        lat
4   20.47559  54.720311
21  20.44220  54.710419
```